# Facebook crawler doesn't follow my rewrite rule

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, user-agent

I have this in my HTACCESS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/1.1|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet|/externalhit_uatext/)
RewriteRule /+(.*?)$ /api/getSocial.php?which=$1 [P]
```

And using the facebook debug tool with my website, I see that facebook is getting the url without being rewritten, which is very weird. This is the url:

```
http://lab.pre.rtve.es/carlos-v-ricardo/podcast/
```

¿Any ideas why the crawler is not following this redirect? ¿Has the name of the user agent changed for Facebook?

I can read in the official documentation that this should work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I’d suggest that you get yourself a browser extension that allows you to manipulate request parameters, and then request your page using the exact User-Agent header that the FB scraper uses according to documentation – and see what you get with that. Also, enable rewrite logging on your server, to see what exactly is going on when that request reaches your server.

Answer (score 1):

In the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler it is also written the crawler can have the

> facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)

useragent, and you do not cover that.

Comment: I tried that before, didn't work. Now the debug tool says "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped". Maybe my htaccess is not well build now.

Comment: Try replacing the facebookexternalhit/1.1 with facebookexternalhit.* to match all cases and see if that works. If not, check the apache logs and see the sent header.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to check apache logs!! I'm trying both things now, cheers mate. I'll Be back in a moment

Comment: I see that Apache is giving a 206 http code. I never saw this before, looks like a "partial response". The problem is that facebook scraper is getting my index.html instead of the content that getSocial.php is delivering. I will edit my question so you can see how my HTACCESS is now.

Comment: Still having this problem :(